# select entire row based on a list of value in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a big file with many rows and columns.

In column D, there are multiple keywords like barber, restaurants, schools etc.
In one cell there are multiple keywords with a comma.

**Now what I want is to filter out rows based on a few hundred keywords in one go.**

I don't want to filter manually, data with 1 or 2 keywords as that will be time consuming for me

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal autofilter, and select in the list all the values you want at once. There is no need of using 1 or 2. In the list of Autofilter, select all the keywords you want to use. Select and clear the check boxes to show values that are found in the column of data.

> [**Filter data by using an
>   AutoFilter**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-08647e19-11d1-42f6-b376-27b932e186e0)

You could record the process with a macro and try to adpat it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But that will not help me as I have multiple keywords in 1 cell example cell A1 auto repair, auto sell, auto resell and in A2 = Auto repair, car wash, car sell and so on. I want to select every cell with auto repair plus many other keywords list that I have in it